# automatic popup in vim with clang_complete plugin

Tags: filetype-c++, filetype-c

I want to use Vim to program in clang (`*.c` and `*.cpp`).
At the moment I am trying to use the clang-complete plugin and I like the autocompletion but I have to use the `<C-n>` or `<C-p>` combinations to make the autocomplete menu appear, and it's annoying I want the menu to appear automatically when I start typing.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Your question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516337/pycharm-like-autocompletion-in-vim/63121397#63121397) question . Check that answer.

Comment: Ya intente con deoplete pero no funciona

Comment: Please write English. Can you explain what happend exactly?